# NetBeans javascript variable highlighting

Tags: javascript, netbeans

[image: code highlighting]

Can anyone tell me why NetBeans (in newest, 7.3 version) is highlighting me so many lines instead of particular variable or other part of code? It happens rarely and only with JavaScript code, but still... it's little annoying :/.

Comment: I'm wondering this same thing. It's incredibly annoying.

Comment: Do You maybe know, if this issue has been reported on NetBeans bug forum?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately.